# Effect of Blood Feud

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Blood Feud lets two creatures fight each other. Is it similar to normal combat?

As I understand it, after a combat you use up your power and toughness. If there are 3/4 and 2/2, and they combat each other, the first one uses 2 powers to kill the other and has remaining 1 power. Its toughness is used up to be 2.

Does the same thing happen and the effect remains till the end of the turn after Blood Feud?

Comment: This question is covered by (but not necessarily a duplicate of) [Does 'fight' involve combat?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7504/6692). Users who end up here might want to give it a look-see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a correct understanding of either combat or fighting.

"Fight" is a special keyword that simply means "the 2 chosen creatures deal damage to the other equal to their power." Neither power nor toughness is ever "used up." If a 2/4 creature fights another 2/4 creature, both will still be a 2/4 creature after that. The only difference will be that they will both be a 2/4 creature with 2 damage on them.

In combat, power and toughness are also not "used up". The attacking and blocking creature will deal damage to the other equal to its power.

Comment: The specific rule about fighting is here: http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Fight

Comment: then does the damage the creature get from a fight transfered to the normal combat in the same turn?

Comment: @JuneKim Yes; you need to go open the [Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/resources/rules/EN_MTGM14_Rulebook_LR.pdf) and re-read about how combat works and how damage works because you seem like you've misunderstood a lot.

Comment: @JuneKim It doesn't matter whether the damage comes from combat, or fighting, or a spell like Shock. All damage is cumulative, and is set back to 0 at the end of each turn.