# What is the result of a combat between creatures of 3/1 and 2/2?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I don't know which one would win a 3/1 creature or a 2/2 creature, or would they both tie. I always thought they would tie.

Comment: Be careful not to use the word "Fight" if what you are talking about is combat. [Fight in MTG is a different thing from combat](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7504/does-fight-involve-combat?rq=1).

Answer (score 10):

Both creatures will die.

From the [MTG Basic Rulebook](https://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/en_mtgm11_rulebook_lr_web.pdf)

> After all blockers are chosen, combat damage is assigned. Each creature — both attackers and blockers — deals damage equal to its power.
>
> If a creature is dealt damage equal to or greater than its toughness over the course of a single turn, that creature is destroyed and goes to its owner’s graveyard.

In your example, after combat damage is done, there will be a 3/1 creature with 2 damage, and a 2/2 creature with 3 damage. Both of these creatures have at least as much damage as toughness, so both will go to the graveyard.

Note that there is no actual concept of "win", "lose", or "tie" in combat. I suppose it's fair to consider it a tie if both your and your opponent's creatures die, but that's not actual terminology in Magic.

Comment: Small note that in MtG player-jargon "trade" refers to creatures mutually destroying each other, especially in combat, which might be a useful replacement.